# Xcode 8 does not show any value of variable when i place on it in debug

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, xcode8

In Debug Mode i am trying to see values of variables but it shows nothing. I use `Xcode8`. Using `Objective - C` and `Swift` classes together. I dont have such problem in `objective-C` part, i can see values clearly. I read lots of posts and answers but none of them helped me. I tried to set optimization level = none under `Swift` compiler in `BuildSettings`. Also tried adding o2 and -O0 to other `linker flags`. I checked edit scheme and it is in debug mode. So i stuck. By the way if i create project with only swift language, i can see values of variables.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you found a way to solve this issue?

Comment: No unfortunately, very annoying. I will update my osx to Sierra, i read somethings about it. It may help.

Comment: try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34065891/363339

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check when you have problems with a new version of Xcode is to make sure that you rebuild all the Swift code (your own and anything you are importing from Carthage or CocoaPods) with the new tools.

If that doesn't help, it is probably best to file a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com; it will probably take some back and forth to figure out what's going wrong and a bug report is a more convenient way to do that.

Comment: Thanks, i rebuilded everything but it is still same. If i open project with swift language, then i have no problem with debugging. When i open project objective-c and add swift classes then i cannot see values in debugging when i place on variable. Pretty weird. İ opened bug to apple.